# Creating Tabs using Drupal?

Tags: 6, nodes

I have been looking for a solution that allows me to add tabs to my website something similar to this [page](http://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/download/#connect).

So far I have been using HTML inside of ckeditor to write all my content. However, now I need to be able to have a form and tabs.

Can someone provide me a module or a solution to have tabs and form ?

Thank you in advance

H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quicktabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) + [Webforms](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform). You can have multiple pages (nodes) or blocks and using the quicktabs module would allows you to have the different insert those pages or blocks into tabs. To created the field form you can used the Webform module and inserted into quick tabs module.

Comment: Hey Darol, thx for your reply, Isn't a easier way to get it work? My problem: the tabs menu an content should be displayed in a node body with some id. The only problem is to render the form under a tab menu. May I have to create a module, if yes which core hook should I implement? Thx in advance

Comment: The quicktabs is going to to have some id.

Comment: Problem solved, THX Darol and you all Guys!

Comment: No Problem @Hermann, if this solve your problem you should mark it as the answer by pressing the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs...allows you to create blocks of tabbed content.

Answer (score 1):

To style fields in that manner, use [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group)

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All
>   fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap
>   their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers
>   like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div
>   wrappers.

To tabbify pieces of text in a single body text, as done in that example, install [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme and read up on the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) (especially tabs and pills). The sited example uses Bootstrap framework.

Please note that Bootstrap theme for Drupal and Bootstrap framework are not synonymous. Bootstrap is a popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework that Bootstrap theme uses. You can use Bootstrap framework without Bootstrap theme, but the question is, would you want to?

If you do not want to use a Bootstrap enabled theme, then I am sure you would find a myriad of Javascript and CSS solution if you google a bit.

Comment: I Reynolds, thx for your answer, Unfortunately I use drupal 6, we plan a upgrade at the end of this years. So I muss write a module that output the same view. I already create my own tabs and styled it like the page showed but the problem, how I can render a form into a tab? taht is my problem. I can pass the html code in a node body where I want to display it, but how I can add a form? May I have to implement a core hook module, if yes which? thx in advance

Comment: I solved the problem using Quicktabs and Webform, for the styling part, it is possible to change the quicktabs css file. I just needed to write some jquery code for ui effect, since d6 is not fully supporting the new jquery-ui

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option [jQuery Tabs Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_jquery_tabs).

> jQuery Tabs Field module allows you to create jQuery Tabs field. Using
>   this you can add upto 7 tabs with tab title and tab body in a node.
>   After saving node, the module will display all these 7 tabs as jQuery
>   tabs.
>
> This module is very useful for content types where you want to display
>   information tabs wise for example product pages etc.

Comment: Hello Scott, thx for your reply, currently I use Drupal 6.34, so the module named above is only for D7.